# how to use one dynamic web project in another?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp

How can call this project in my controller of another dynamic web project i am having trouble in specifying the url

this is the web.xml of the project which i want to use

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JAXRS-HelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

this is the class of project which i want to use in controller

```css
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Path("/helloWorldREST")
public class HelloWorldREST {

 @GET
 @Path("/{parameter}")
 public Response responseMsg( @PathParam("parameter") String parameter,
   @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("value") String value) {

  String output = "Hello from: " + parameter + " : " + value;
        
  return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
 }
}
```

this is the controller where i want to use the url of the project

```
angular.module('videoManagement')
.factory('videoService' ,
['$http',function($http){
    var factory={};

    factory.ali=function(){
        return $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'/Project_name/HelloWorldREST/responseMsg',
            header:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            params:{
                value:"aliasadsaeekhan"
            }
        });

    }

    return factory;

}]);
```

i am  new to angularjs kindly help me out...

Comment: What error you got??

Comment: its not going in .succes function when i am call the function ali                                                                                                              this is where i am calling it                                                                                                                    angular
.module('videoManagement')
.controller('videoController',
['$scope','videoService',
 function($scope , videoService)
 {
 
 videoService.ali().success(function(response){
  $scope.anya="abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz";
 })
 }]);

Comment: try to use absolute url than relative

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues as to status, what is sent/returned , url used etc.

Comment: the  value="aliasadsaeekhan" which you are sending is a query param not a path param

Comment: In browser i have changed the path by  going in Network window in inspect Element (Right Click on page) i have corrected the path and the page giving the 200k return msg... I think the problem is the content-type...